# angular bootstrap UI settings

Tags: angularjs

Angular UI Bootstrap settings:
I want to active the second tabs is default.
Reference url :
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
In tabs section

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.4.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
  angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function($scope, $window) {});
</script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
  <uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title" active="false">Static content</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="1" heading="Static title">Static content</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="2" heading="Second">Second</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="3" heading="Third">Third</uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share code you tried

Comment: <div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl"><uib-tabset active="active"> <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title" active="false">Static content</uib-tab><uib-tab index="1" heading="Static title" >Static content</uib-tab>
      <uib-tab index="2" heading="Second" >Second</uib-tab> </uib-tabset></div>